# Como unir dos tablas en sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Supongamos que tengo dos tablas con los mismos nombres de columnas y la única diferencia es que una es la continuación de la otra, ¿como hago que se unan las dos tablas (una a continuación de la otra) para obtener todos los datos en una sola consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tus tablas tienen los mismos campos puedes usar un

> UNION

algo así

```
SELECT v1 FROM t1
 UNION
SELECT v2 FROM t2;
```

te dejo un link con más información al respecto

[SQLITE UNION](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-union/)

Comment: Eso es más simple de lo que pensé, muchas gracias!